# How can I find the total amount of employees in each gender, that are currently working in each year?

Tags: mysql

The employees table

[image: The employees table]

The dept_emp table

[image: The dept_emp table]

```
SELECT
    COUNT(de.emp_no) AS num_of_employees,
    e.gender AS gender, 
    YEAR(de.from_date) AS year
FROM employees e
JOIN dept_emp de
    USING (emp_no)
GROUP BY gender, year
ORDER BY year
```

Using this code, I am able to get the following query results

Failed Results

[image: Failed Results]

What I solved here is being able to get the hired number of employees in each year sorted by its gender.

The question I am trying to solve is:
How many males and females have worked throughout the company, showing a running total in each year of active employees during that year.

The problem however, is that I am unable to get the currently active working employees in each year and gender on a running total, since I am using the from_date column and therefore am not taking into account on people leaving the job/unemployed from the to_date column in the dept_emp table.

I spent 10 hours straight trying to figure this out yesterday and half of the day today. Some other codes I used are here, but no luck. Putting this one out here in case maybe there is something I missed etc.

```
SET @total := 0;
SELECT 
    gender,
    year,
    hired_employees,
@total := @total + hired_employees AS currently_employed
FROM
(SELECT 
    COUNT(de.emp_no) AS hired_employees,
    e.gender AS gender,
    YEAR(de.from_date) AS year
FROM dept_emp de
JOIN employees e
    USING (emp_no)
WHERE gender = "M" 
GROUP BY gender, year
ORDER BY gender, year) AS male_employees
```

[failed running total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfnGM.png)

I get the running total here, in this case for all male employees, but cannot add AND gender = "F" in the where clause, as the running total aren't separate from each gender. Still no luck in sorting out active vs inactive employees per year in this code as well.

Any help would be so much greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.x? Then you can use window functions to get running totals in each partition.

Comment: Using the latest version and had no luck with the over clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think that something that might help would be making a calendar table and then joining against that to do your grouping.  Assuming you have a calendar table, I think a query like this would get you what you are looking for

```
SELECT cal.y AS `year`
  , SUM(IF(e.gender = 'M', 1, 0)) AS male_count
  , SUM(IF(e.gender = 'F', 1, 0)) AS female_count
FROM reference.calendar cal
LEFT JOIN dept_emp de ON (cal.y > YEAR(de.from_date) AND cal.y < YEAR(de.to_date))
LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.emp_no = dept_emp.emp_no
WHERE cal.y BETWEEN [your desired range]
GROUP BY cal.y
```

[Here](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables) are some good instructions for creating a robust calendar table.

Comment: Looked into it but still no luck. it seems like nobody online has a similar problem to this, despite using the same database. people seem to use the question "how many people are hired per year" rather than "how many people are currently employed per year" which is interesting.. probably better to use python with a loop increment for this?

Comment: @HubbsBuns here is a link with instructions on how to create a good calendar table.  http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables I've edited my answer to include this link too.  What do you mean when you say "looked into it but still no luck"?  You should find that the answer I provide does answer the question "how many people are currently employed per year"